# Multi field validation in custom list - code not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, validation, multiple-values

I have a custom list with JavaScript to toggle the choice field. I now need to validate the fields according to the selection. My code below throws and error - incorrect syntax.

```
=IF([Red_Blue]="Red",
IF([Red_Variety]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
=IF([Red_Blue]="Red",
IF([Red_Minor]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
=IF([Red_Blue]="Blue",
IF([Blue_Variety]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
=IF([Red_Blue]="Blue",
IF([Blue_Minor]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare 4 Formulas in 1

A Formula starts with one **=** and one **=** only

Also note that:

=IF([Red_Variety]<>"",TRUE,FALSE)

is exactly the same as:

=NOT(ISBLANK([Red_Variety]))

Comment: ok - not sure of the syntax for both would this be: =NOT(ISBLANK([Red_Variety])) =NOT(ISBLANK([Blue_Variety])) - do I need a comma or semi comma after each statement?

Comment: This doesn't work for me - the Red_Variety & Blue_Variety are options of a choice field - I just get a syntax error when trying to add as validation.

Comment: Start in Excel, itseasier to develop, if you name your Excel cells with the SPnames your Formula will be exaclty the same. On non-english env. the separator could be a ;

Comment: I just cant get this to work - the closest I have gotten is:  =IF([Red_Blue]="Red",
IF([Red_Variety]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE) - I have gone back to this as I cant see how =NOT(ISBLANK([Red_Variety])) will work. The problem is I am trying to validate fields that are based on selection. Would I be better to use javascript?

Comment: If you feel more confident with JS then you can use the ``PreSaveAction``

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a solution I thought I would post my outcome.
I have a form with toggle fields and I needed the validation to align with the choice field. I am not able to use InfoPath as it is not compatible with all our users. The below validation is a result of creating a toggle form using JS and then the conditional validation statement in the SP settings.

I hope it is of some use for those who are looking for solutions other than OOTB.

The Drop list is a choice - RED or BLUE
The RED choice needs to ensure the RED_VARIETY and the RED_MINOR text fields have validation control.
The BLUE choice needs to ensure the BLUE_VARIETY and the BLUE_MINOR text fields have validation control.
Most importantly I need the validation to only apply to the conditions.

I have added the validation statement to my SP custom list under my list> Settings > Validation

```
IF(AND(ISBLANK([Red_Variety])=TRUE,[Red_Blue]=”Red”),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK(Red_Minor)=TRUE,[Red_Blue]=”Red”),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK([Blue_Variety])=TRUE,[Red_Blue]=”Blue”),FALSE,
IF(AND(ISBLANK(Blue_Minor)=TRUE,[Red_Blue]=”Blue”),FALSE,TRUE))
```

This works with my [toggle form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185974/show-hide-fields-in-sp)